# property to get value in the input box

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program that asks for the amount of a purchase, then calculates the discounted price.  The function works but the property innerHTML only work if i set it in a  paragraph p>.  I want it to print out in the input>.  So my question is what property do I need to use.

Error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```
<body>   
<p>Enter amount of purchases:<input type =" text" id ="purchase_amount" onkeyup ="calculate_discount()"/></p>
<p>Discount price:<input type="text" id =" discount_amount"/></p>
</body>

function calculate_discount() {
var purchase_amount = document.getElementById("purchase_amount").value;
var answer;
if (purchase_amount >= 10) 
{
    answer = purchase_amount - (purchase_amount * .10);
}
else if (purchase_amount < 10) 
{
    answer = purchase_amount;
}
document.getElementById("discount_amount").innerHTML = answer;
```

}

Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/xK4s4/

Comment: You get the error because the ID of the element contains a space. Remove it and use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove whitespace in id attribute of discount amount input element

> id=" discount_amount"
>
> Set value instead of innerHTML.
>
> Make sure your script is placed before input element.
>
> Work script:

```
<script>
    function calculate_discount() {
        var purchase_amount = document.getElementById("purchase_amount").value;
        var answer;
        if (purchase_amount >= 10) 
        {
            answer = purchase_amount - (purchase_amount * .10);
        }
        else if (purchase_amount < 10) 
        {
            answer = purchase_amount;
        }
        document.getElementById("discount_amount").value = answer;
    }
</script>

<body>   
  Enter amount of purchases:
  <input type="text" id="purchase_amount" onkeyup="calculate_discount()"/>

  Discount price:
  <input type="text" id="discount_amount"/>
</body>
```

[Demo in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/k5qZL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLrXT/)

Input elements don't use the `innerHTML` property, instead set the `value` property.

```
document.getElementById("discount_amount").value = answer;
```

Other issues:

In the fiddle, you run the code `onload`, this means that your function is out of the global scope and can't be called by the keyup event. Change to `no wrap - in head`.

You have a space before the discount_amount element ID:

```
<p>Discount price:<input type="text" id =" discount_amount"/></p>
```

Comment: `value` has to be used, but `input` elements still have an `innerHTML` property (afaik) and that doesn't explain the error.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, it's that plus the space plus the onload. Well, the onload is only a problem in the fiddle, his code differs from that because he is getting as far as the error whereas the fiddle doesn't.